# PROC GENMOD: I get non-estimable least squares means, but an estimable difference in least squares means

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, lsmeans

I ran a PROC GENMOD code in SAS (see below).  Q is a binary variable, while X and W and ternary variables.  The output shows that the least squares means for both levels of a binary variable, "Q", are non-estimable.  **However, there is an estimated difference in least squares means between "Q = 1" and "Q = 0".**

*How is this possible?*  I thought that the difference in least squares means is calculated by subtracting the 2 least squares means.  **If both of my least squares means are non-estimable, then how can my difference in least squares means be estimable?**

Thanks for your thoughts.

```
proc genmod

    data = mydata;

    class Q (ref = '0')

    X (ref = '1')

    W (ref = '1')

    R;

    model successes/trials
                           =
                               Q
                               X
                               W
                               X * W
                               Q * X
                               Q * W
                               / dist = bin
                               link = logit;
                               repeated
                               subject = R;


                               lsmeans Q / exp diff cl e;
                               lsmeans X / exp diff cl e;
                               lsmeans W / exp diff cl e;
                               lsmeans X * W / exp diff cl e;
                               lsmeans Q * X / exp diff cl e;
                               lsmeans Q * W / exp diff cl e;
    run;
```

Comment: It is definitely possible. Estimable functions are in the row space of X and it is easy to construct examples where it works out this way.